# Creating a unique shortcut when installing an app behaves differently on different Android version

Tags: android, android-intent

I use the following codes to create a shortcut when installing an app:

in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<!-- for creating a shortcut in the home screen -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

in onCreate() of the main activity:

```
// an Intent to create a shortCut
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    //repeat to create is forbidden
    shortcutIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    //set the name of shortCut
    shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, this.getString(R.string.app_name));
    //set icon
    Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
    //set the application to lunch when you click the icon
    shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT
            , new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity.class));
    //sendBroadcast,done
    sendBroadcast(shortcutIntent);
```

These codes work fine in Android 4.0.4, which creates an shortcut at the first time and send a toast saying the shortcut already exists after the 1st time installation. But in Android 4.2.2, I can create many duplicated shortcuts by clicking the back key and enter the app again.

Is there any way to work on both version of Android ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

shortcutIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false) is not working in 4.2 version. i think you have to use some other ways to create unique shortcut.

If failour then just uninstall the shortcut and install again.something like :

```
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);             
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

and in manifest use both UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT and INSTALL_SHORTCUT permissions.

And this rough idea is nicely working on every versions.